# how to search inside specific block of html?

Tags: jquery

`temp =  $.jstree._focused().get_selected().html()`

Gave me a block of html. There is a **button** inside of that html:

```
<button class="square_button button_background" type="button" onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics')">
 run
</button>
```

How can I search ONLY inside **temp** variable and get the value of `onclick`?

I am asking **jQuery code** that **searches** inside **temp** variable for **button** and gives me **onclick**.

Note that temp **is not equal only** `<button class="square_button button_background" type="button" onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics')">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the actual HTML, search within `$.jstree._focused().get_selected()` using `find()`.

e.g.

`$.jstree._focused().get_selected().find('button').first().attr('onclick')`

Does that work?

Comment: @Greg: great suggestion. your code gives me `function onclick(event) {
    run_through_ajax("login", "basics");
}` how can I get only `run_through_ajax("login", "basics")` and then call it from my js code? I tried to add .text() after your code but it's not valid.

Comment: If you just want to trigger the code that is called in the onclick event of that element, rather than trying to extract the Javascript and manually run it using `eval()`, which is not a good idea and generally considered bad practise, why not just use jQuery to trigger the click on the button? Then the onclick will work as normal.

Comment: In order to trigger the click, use jQuery's `click()` method. i.e. `$.jstree._focused().get_selected().find('button').first().click();`

Comment: @Greg: always thinking outside the box? You didn't answer my question but you helped me to do what I wanted to do. I thought I need the search .... I am not sure if @maarons is going to finish what he started as I am accept your answer. Any chance you help me with the search? I want to lear...

Comment: one more question... how to use eval() ? `$.jstree._focused().get_selected().find('button').first().attr('onclick').eval();` didn't work

Comment: `eval()` is not a jQuery function, it is a standard javascript function that runs any javascript code as a string. e.g. `eval('alert("Hello, sir!");');` will display the alert. However, as with all similar techniques, running dynamic code can be a vulnerability and exploited by malicious users. So try to avoid it. :-)

Comment: And yes, I tend to think outside the box a fair bit. It can be both a good and a bad attribute to have. Sometimes employers just want someone who "does what they are told". :-)

Comment: @Radek, If you did really want to search through the string of HTML as you asked, though, you would use regular expressions. e.g. `var onclick = temp.replace(/<button.*onclick="([^"]+)".*/gi, "$1"); eval(onclick);` See sites like (http://regular-expressions.info) for good explanations of Regular Expressions. As a programmer, you need to know Regular Expressions. They are very powerful tools. Good luck!

Comment: @Greg, no, I'm not going to use search. I very much like your `solution` I just wanted to know how to do 'search'. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Modified for demo:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">some stuffs here</div>
    <button class="square_button button_background" type="button" onclick="run_through_ajax('login','basics')"> run </button>
    some other stuffs here
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

`console.log($('#foo button').attr('onclick'));`

Is that what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/FqHgz/

Comment: I updated the question saying that want to search within `test` variable and your fiddle with the content of this variable. I am after something like @maarons suggests

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for.  Find searches only in children of top element so you'd probably want to wrap HTML you want to search in, in some div.

```
$('<div>' + html_i_want_to_search + '</div>').find('button');
```

Comment: this is exactly what I asked for. Your code returns `[object Object]` if I add `.attr('onlick')` it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the onclick for that you could

```
var prop = $("button.square_button button_background").attr("onclick");
```